# Notification when azure storage blob trigger event on storage queue

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-functions

On azure blob storage, when a blob file is added to the storage container, I have configured a message is to be sent to a storage queue. I have used a storage queue as there will a low number of daily files loaded to storage container. I am able to consume the message using the CloudQueueClient. As I have java spring boot app, is there any way to get triggered when a new message appears on the storage queue. Using some sort of Listener rather than polling continuously.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this would work for you but you can take a look at storage queue triggered Azure Function. That Function will be automatically invoked when a message appears in the Storage Queue.

Comment: Have you explored Event grid? Storage queues expected the receiver to pull the message from it. Whereas Event grid pushes the message to the subscriber.  That way, you don't need to poll at all. Check this link for more info. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview

Comment: Yes, configured a event hub trigger when file inserted into blob storage, so message pushed on event hub(ampq or kafka) when file inserted.